# Is there a cheatsheet for tabulator's internal API, for example similar to cell.getData()?

Tags: javascript, dom, tabulator

So, is there a cheat sheet for the tabulator's internal API, for example, there's cell.getData(), but what are the others available for cell, row, column and table? And are there other components?

Currently, I'm accessing the objects directly, but I expect it to break since these objects are prefixed with "_", for example, "_row" and I'd like to use the actual API present.

Thank you for your attention (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the components:

http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/components

For table methods:

http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/update